# Долгая загрузка.

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM notifications INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.vk_id = notifications.from WHERE notifications.type = 'user_login' ORDER BY notifications.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

С чем может быть связана долгая загрузка при подключении данного запроса? В таблице **notifications** около 400.000 записей...

Comment: индекса по type нету, да? и сделайте его числовым.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, как поставить индекс? И мне не надо числовым его делать.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, попробывал добавить полнотекстовый индекс. Но не помогло.

Comment: нет. обычный index. primary у вас уже есть и он может быть только один. не уверен, что понял какой индекс вы добавили, но скорее всего не то.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, https://195.43.82.129/myadmin/themes/dot.gif и рядом написано добавить индекс. Это то?

Comment: Modal, Верно

Comment: @Node_pro, база грузилась 84 секунды, когда поставил. А на деле всё равно медленно... В самом запросе может что-то надо изменить?

Comment: А насчет моего 5 варианта, может его рассмотритеть? Ведь кэшь хорошая штука, как для оптимизации)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня есть несколько вариантов:

- Вариант №1, если Вам не надо все поля таблиц
     можно попробовать перечислить, чем
     использовать (*).
- Вариант №2, как сказал Yura Ivanov,
     поставить index на поле Type (НЕ
     PRIMARY, а index), должно дать
     быстрее обработку. В phpmyadmin там
     есть кнопочка "index" во вкладке
     "Структура".
- Вариант №3, поле type - числовой. Например: 1 -
     user_login, 2 - user_email ....
- Вариант №4, по умолчанию поставить
     сортировку в настройки таблицы (Но
     тут надо подумать, все зависит от
     вашего проекта).
- Вариант №5, если
     запрос не динамический т.е ( редко
     меняется), можно воспользоваться так
     званым cache.
  **Удачи!**

Comment: @Node_pro, как раз-таки запрос динамический ><

Comment: А насчет №3? Также есть вариант поделить таблицу (по месяцам, по алфавиту...)

Comment: @Node_pro, более 400.000 записей переделывать. Вы с ума сошли? :)

Comment: а в чем проблема, можно же написать програмку какая все сделает заместь вас ;). Если вас смущает 3 вариант, можно сделать, что-то вроде `update `notifications` SET `type` = 1 Where `type`="user_login"`

Comment: @Node_pro, о, точно! Помечаю Ваш ответ как правильный. Сейчас приступлю!

Comment: =), желаю хороших успехов =)

Comment: И перед началом лучше бы сделать бэкап таблицы, а то можно опечататься и лишиться всех записей)